# Python: convert object column into datetime and compare with current date

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, type-conversion

My dataframe has a column containing dates like

```
+-----+---------------------+
| Nr  |        Date         |
+-----+---------------------+
| 146 | 2011-03-11 00:00:00 |
| 654 | 2014-05-16 00:00:00 |
| 312 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 |
| 675 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
```

Now I want to convert them (current type object) into type datetime within the dataframe and compare them with the current date.

For conversion, I tried

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but it returns error:

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00

Result should be the same dataframe, but only with valid dates. So all rows with dates that already passed should be dropped, only future dates remain:

```
+-----+---------------------+
| Nr  |        Date         |
+-----+---------------------+
| 312 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00 |
| 675 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |
+-----+---------------------+
```

Thank you for supporting.

Comment: a little curious here; why you think the results should be only with valid dates and have dropped the invalid ones for you ? have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), unless you pass in the explicitly different `error` arg value, you are not getting what you expected/stated above. In short, pandas is not happy about your `9999`.

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors= 'coerce')`  or if you want to omit the invalid dates use `errors = 'ignore'`

Comment: This does not work. Each date `9999-12-31 00:00:00`, becomes `NaT` then

Comment: As far as I can see, it is not possible to do what you want. The max. time Pandas can deal with is `pd.Timestamp.max = Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')`. Your options are to `ignore` the error and pass the string, or `coerce` the error and pass NaT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep only future dates, and you want to keep your dates with years 9999, you could do something like:

```
df['Date'][(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce') > pd.to_datetime('today')) | (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce').isnull())]
```

This will work for the data you have shown but will pass True for any NaTs, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas uses a timestamp represented in a nanosecond resolution. Since the timestamp is stored in a 64-bit number, the span of the timestamp is limited and should lie between a certain range.

The range is specified [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)

Comment: That is why I am asking for help. Dates are as mentioned so I need a solution that can work with it. It is not necessary to convert into datetime. But as described, I need a dataframe only containing future dates.

Answer (score 0):

This **OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00** error is because you are converting string to datetime with year **9999**.

The timestamp limitations in pandas is only for 584 years (1677-2262)