# How do I check if a date is out of bound in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, boundary

If I have this date of example: `10/10/9999`
When I try to use it with pandas I get this error:

```
 pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp:
```

How do I check if the date is within the pandas date time boundaries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas out of bounds nanosecond timestamp after offset rollforward plus adding a month offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a)

Comment: Or somewhere in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743948/python-convert-object-column-into-datetime-and-compare-with-current-date

Comment: The point is that while numpy allows various resolutions for its `datetime64` dtype pandas only use `datetime64(ns)`